# F-22 Air Dominance Fighter compatibility on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, f-22-air-dominance-fighter

I know, we're talking about history but 2 days ago I got my hand on this wonderful combat flight simulator but I can't manage to play with it. I've installed it and no problem with that.
I've tried to set the compatibility option but no success.
I don't know, maybe a windows 98 emulator?

OS: Windows 7 32-bit but it does the same on XP 32-bit. The game simply doesn't start, when I clicck on the icon I got the prompt of windows which signals the crash.

Comment: It would help if you could specify precisely what Windows version you have (including whether it's 32 or 64 bit) and exactly what errors you encounter when trying to play the game.

Comment: @Oak♦: I wanted to add a game specific tag, but [f-22-air-dominance-fighter] is too long, any suggestions?

Comment: @Tobias I suggest [f-22-adf]. Lame but I can't think of any better option.

Comment: @Oak: added the infos and I wanted to set the tag f-22-adf but I still haven't the permission.

Comment: Twelve years later, they've increased the tag max length limit to 35 so I've added the tag.

Comment: and I still can't play this game! (And I still have the original box and CD!)

Answer (score 2):

I've not played that game myself, but if it's not too graphically or processor intensive, you may be able to run it in a virtual machine running an earlier version of windows that is compatible with the game.

This is unlikely to work if the game is especially graphics or processor intensive because you need enough resources to support the virtual machine running the game as well as your installed operating system/

Answer (score 1):

Have you got music enabled? this will usually cause F22 ADF to crash.